# Variable isn't receiving the method's return value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, return

```
def return_node(self, head, position):
    if position == 0:
        # return the node correctly
        return head
    else:
        self.return_node(head.next_node, position - 1)

def insert_at_position(self, head, data, position):
    if position == 0:
        self.insert_first(head, data)
    elif position == self.length:
        self.insert_last(head, data)
    else:
        previous_node = self.return_node(head, position - 1)
        # previous_node's value is None instead of the method's return value
        next_node = self.return_node(head, position)
        # same here
        new_node = Node(data, next_node)
        previous_node.next_node = new_node
        self.length += 1
```

I'm trying to implement a method in my linked list that insert a node at a specific position. The problem is: the variables 'previous_node' and 'next_node' are not getting the values properly.
Instead of the node value they are getting None. Thank you guys!

Comment: return_node's `else` doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: You probably meant to do `return self.return_node(head.next_node, position - 1)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
else:
  self.return_node(head.next_node, position - 1)
```

Will not return anything, because there is no **return** keyword.

`return self.return_node(head.next_node, position - 1)`

Will do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your variables are being set to `None`, is because that is the default value returned from a function if no value to return is provided:

```
def foo(): 
    pass 


>>> type(foo())
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Because the `else` clause inside of `return_node()` does not return a value, Python returns `None`. If you want to call `return_node` recursively and return the value returned by the subsequent call, you need to use `return`:

```
def return_node(self, head, position):
    if position == 0:
        # return the node correctly
        return head
    else:
        return self.return_node(head.next_node, position - 1) # use return
```